# LDAPS bind performance from Java

Tags: java, ldap

I used the code below to authenticate users from a stand alone java application:

```
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;


public class Authenticate
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();

        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "LDAPS://my_ldap_server:636");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,
            "CN=0@0.com,CN=myCustomers,CN=PartX,DC=testCom,DC=local");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "user_password");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            new InitialDirContext(env);
            // send request, wait for response
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Round trip response time = "
                + (end - start) + " millis");
        }

        System.out.println("Welcome");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

I get a response time of near to 200 ms per bind, which is very high. My question is what response times do others see while performing an LDAP bind from java.

There must be other approaches to bind users against LDAP. Please share your approaches. I have a .NET implementation of the bind operation and it performs at about 20 ms. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello experts. Any other inputs please? Specifically to the response times seen by other java implementations binding users.

Answer (score 0):

According to Oracle's implementation of LDAP/LDAPS authentication - with or without connection pool - an LDAPClient is created. This lDAPClient creates an LDAPConnection and after performing a bind/authenticate, closes the connection.

If the connection pool property is set to true, then only if the security principal and password are the same, a pooled connection is used.

In the case of a web application, with a million users, we should not pool connections. This will overload the ldap server.

The ldap client and connection code is in the java rt.jar. In the case of ldaps/ssl, a delay is observed as against ldap without ssl.

If a way is found where the ldap client is instructed to use the same ldap connection object - just like we do with jdbc connections - then ldap authentications can be considerably optimized.

Ldap connection pooling makes sense when we attempt to search for users only, not when we attempt to perform an authentication.

In short, I agree with the original poster. There is a performance delay when using LDAPS authentication. I would also like to hear what others experiences are.

Comment: How will pooling connections overload the LDAP server and not pooling connections overload it less? And how exactly is connection pooling different from "a way ... where the ldap client is instructed to use the same ldap connection object"?

Answer (score -1):

1. Your test isn't valid. You aren't closing the InitialContext. And in a normal system you would probably enable LDAP connection-pooling, which would change the picture completely.
2. LDAP binding isn't a rate-determining step, but I'm pretty sure mine go faster than this.
3. The only other way to bind via LDAP in Java JNDI is via `LdapContext.reconnect()`, but under the hood it will be doing exactly the same things on the wire.